# Как наложить несколько событий на кнопку, чтобы они отрабатывали по условию?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-form

Есть форма поиска. Сейчас при клике на кнопку - разворачивается форма и сразу начинается поиск по пустому слову. Как сделать так, чтобы по кнопке поиска только раскрывалась форма и до ввода данных пользователем `action` не срабатывал, а после уже введенных данных пользователем - кнопка уже отрабататывала, как `submit`, и при этом она же сворачивалась, как сейчас? Если же пользователь ничего не ввел после раскрытия формы, то при нажатия на кнопку - форма просто сворачивалась и ничего не происходило.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.searchformhead .searchSubmit').click(function() {
    $(this).prev().animate({
      width: 'toggle'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.searchformhead {
  text-align:center;
}
.searchSubmit {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.s {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="searchformhead" method="get" action="#">
  <input type="text" name="s" class="s" size="30" value="Поиск" onfocus="if (this.value = '') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Поиск';}">
  <input type="submit" class="searchSubmit" value="&#xf002;">
</form>
```

Comment: $(this).prev().animate({
      width: 'toggle'
    });
После этого попробуйте доабвить `return false;`. Это должно отменить отправку формы. А вообще стоит ловить отправку не по клику на кнопку, а по `.submit` на форме.

Comment: Короче говоря схема такая: ловите событие `.on("submit", function() {});` по форме (не по кнопке!), потом проверяете, (1) есть ли что-нибудь в строке поиска, (2), имеется ли класс `.opened` у строки. Если хотя бы одно условие истинно, то не препятствуете отправке. Если нет, то выдвигаете строку и добавляете ей класс `.opened`. В общем ориентируетесь на 2 условия: заполненность поля и наличие класса (выдвинуто ли поле), и в зависимости от условий определяете, что делать при отправке формы: отправлять ее или открывать поле.

Comment: @smellyshovel попробовал сделать как вы сказали ниже, но отправляет и пустую строку тоже..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.js-search-form').each(function() {
    var $search = $(this),
      $field = $('.js-search-form_field', $search);

    $search.on('submit', function(e) {
      $field
        .animate({
          width: 'toggle'
        })
        .focus();

      if (!$field.val()) {
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {                                // Эти строчки нужны лишь для демонстрации
        console.log(`Send ${$field.val()}`);  // и должны быть удалены на реальном
        $field.val('');                       // проекте
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.searchformhead {
  text-align: center;
}
.searchSubmit {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.s {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="searchformhead js-search-form" method="get" action="#">
  <input type="text" name="s" class="s js-search-form_field" size="30" placeholder="Поиск">
  <input type="submit" class="searchSubmit" value="&#xf002;">
</form>
```

Comment: а у меня такой вопрос: переношу на реальный сервер 1 в 1, только в `action` указываю `action="<?php  echo home_url(); ?>"` - в адресной строке получаю `http://domen.com/?s=`, т.е. не считывает введенную инфу. если же прописывать `action="#"`, то получаю на выходе `http://domen.com/?s=#` с тем же результатом.. это почему так и как можно поправить?

Answer (score 0):

Так уже лучше, но отправляет и пустую строку..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.searchformhead').on('submit', function() {
    if (!($(this).find('input.s') == '') && !($(this).find('input.s') == 'Поиск') && $(this).find('input.s').hasClass('opened')) {
      $(this).find('input.s').removeClass('opened').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
      });
      console.log("send");
    } else if (!$(this).find('input.s').hasClass('opened')) {
      $(this).find('input.s').addClass('opened').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
      });
    } else {
      $(this).find('input.s').removeClass('opened').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.searchformhead {
  text-align: center;
}
.searchSubmit {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.s {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form class="searchformhead" method="get" action="#">
  <input type="text" name="s" class="s" size="30" value="Поиск" onfocus="if (this.value = '') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Поиск';}">
  <input type="submit" class="searchSubmit" value="&#xf002;">
</form>
```

Comment: Данное сообщение не является ответом. Вы можете отредактировать вопрос, дополнив его новыми данными